# How to unit test legacy application which abuses static?

Tags: java, unit-testing, ejb-3.0

I have inherited a legacy Java 1.5 project which uses EJBs 3.0 and has no tests.

I'm trying to create some unit tests but the code is all entangled with static calls. The following class is called every time an access to a business interface is needed:

```
public final class EJBHelper {

    private static InitialContext context;

    static {
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
           ...
        }
    }

    public static Object getBean(String entity) throws NamingException {
        return context.lookup("PROJECT_EAR/" + entity + "Bean/local");
    }
}
```

In each class this code is repeated for each EJB bean that's needed:

```
public class SomeService {
    private static SomeBean someBean;
    private static SomeBean getSomeBean() throws NamingException {
        if (someBean== null) {
            someBean= (SomeBean) EJBHelper.getBean("some");
        }
        return someBean;
    }

    private static AnotherBean anotherBean;
    private static AnotherBean getAnotherBean() throws NamingException {
        if (anotherBean == null) {
            anotherBean= (AnotherBean ) EJBHelper.getBean("another");
        }
        return anotherBean;
    }

    public doSomething() {
        getSomeBean().findAll(...)

        getAnotherBean().makePersistent(...)
    }    
}
```

How should I refactor this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need for the static classes to be static? If not, I would try to refactor them into non-static classes and then inject the dependencies into your Service classes via constructor.

Comment: I'm still investigating. I was thinking of creating some factories to unify these calls.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I think the key is to refactor the static classes into instance classes that implement interfaces, and then use those interfaces throughout your class so that you can stub/mock, etc.

If you absolutely need the static classes, a possible (I've never tried it) but ugly workaround might be to expose a way in your static class to allow you to inject your fake methods so that you can basically stub out the behavior of your static methods in your unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @WilWang I guess the ugly workaround you describe is the safest solution.